# Is there a distribution where the data is generated from a decision process?

Tags: distributions, decision-theory

Sometimes my data is the result of the decisions each individuum of the observed population made: how much invest, how much gambled etc. The outcome would be a metric variable: money spent in total by the observed population as result of the decision(s).

I have the impression the distribution of the residuals after a regression on some explanatory variables in this kind of data is not normal but rather right-skewed.

Now I wonder if there is some theory that proposes a class of "decision process distributions" whose parameter have some meaningful interpretations.

I skimmed a book on "discrete choice" but I did not find something in this direction.

Any hint appreciated!

Comment: Is the response variable time to make the decision, some binomial decision outcome, a multi-categorical (multinomial) decision outcome, or something else?

Comment: The response would be money spent in total. I edited the question.

Comment: Do you mean Markov Chain: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain ?

Comment: How can a Markov Chain lead to right-skewed continuous distribution? What would be the states of the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Money spent is a count variable and as such is 0 bounded and rightward skewed except in special circumstances. It matters little the process that goes into it to generate that general shape because it's just the shape of count variables. Consider how arbitrary this is by noting that it would be just about as meaningful to discuss the money not spent and then you'd have left skewed and right bounded.

That's not to say that there aren't features of the particular shape of a given distribution that you can use to say something about the decision processes required to generate observed data. There are a variety of models for such kinds of data and some may have been well developed in your field that you're unaware of. You might start looking at Poisson models.